# Is the Stone Cech compactification $\beta\omega$ of $\omega$ radial?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, ordinals

$\beta\omega$ is sequentially discrete, that is, every convergent sequence is eventually constant. Thus, since the space is not discrete, the space is not sequential, that is, it's untrue that every limit point of every set is witnessed by a sequence from the set converging to it.

Is $\beta\omega$ radially discrete, that is, every convergent transfinite sequence is eventually constant? If not, is the space still radial, that is, every limit point of every set is witnessed by a transfinite sequence from the set converging to it?

Comment: Any radial Hausdorff space $X$ satisfies $|X|\leq2^{d(X)}$. This discounts $\beta\omega$ from being radial. In fact, $\beta\omega$ is not even pseudoradial, since no transfinite sequence in $\omega$ converges to any point of $\omega^\ast$. As for radial discreteness, I managed to confuse myself. KP Hart claims [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398022/convergence-properties-in-dense-subsets-of-omega) that the set of P-points is radial. This need not have the subspace topology inherited from $\beta\omega$ after radialisation, but it should still map continuously onto its image there.

Comment: Thanks - I mis-posed my question: if we had radial discreteness then we'd have a proof it's *not* radial, but as you point out, the fact that $\omega$ is radially closed is all we need to disprove pseudoradial. Then I think KP/Alan's note says under CH there exists an $\omega_1$ sequence of P-points converging to another P-point, contradicting radial discreteness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $\beta\omega$ can be quickly seen to not be radial, or even pseudoradial: $\omega$ is a radially closed (since it is countable and sequentially closed) subset which is not closed.

However, it is [consistently not radially discrete](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398022/convergence-properties-in-dense-subsets-of-omega#comment1195759_398192): under $CH$ each $P$-point has a local ordered basis of size $\omega_1$, so each $P$-point has an $\omega_1$-sequence of $P$-points converging to it.